# Read URL from XML data

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-2010, msxml6, txmldocument

Using Delphi 2010 I want to read the URL's for Location, Smartcard_Location and Integrated_Location from the following XML sample data (I left out parts I don't need) using TXMLDocument:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PNAgent_Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Request>
        <Enumeration>
            <Location replaceServerLocation="true" modifiable="true" forcedefault="false" RedirectNow="false">http://2003xa/Citrix/PNAgent/enum.aspx</Location>
            <Smartcard_Location replaceServerLocation="true">https://2003xa/Citrix/PNAgent/smartcard_enum.aspx</Smartcard_Location>
            <Integrated_Location replaceServerLocation="true">http://2003xa/Citrix/PNAgent/integrated_enum.aspx</Integrated_Location>
            <Refresh>
                <OnApplicationStart modifiable="false" forcedefault="true">true</OnApplicationStart>
                <OnResourceRequest modifiable="false" forcedefault="true">false</OnResourceRequest>
                <Poll modifiable="false" forcedefault="true">
                    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                    <Period>6</Period>
                </Poll>
            </Refresh>
        </Enumeration>
    </Request>
</PNAgent_Configuration>
```

The data is already loaded from a webserver into a TXMLDcoument. What is the easiest way to parse this data and get the URL's into string values?

Comment: Simply use `xpath` and selectSingleNode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `getElementsByTagName`:

```
lx1.Items.Add(XMLDocument1.DOMDocument.getElementsByTagName('Location').item[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
lx1.Items.Add(XMLDocument1.DOMDocument.getElementsByTagName('Smartcard_Location').item[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
lx1.Items.Add(XMLDocument1.DOMDocument.getElementsByTagName('Integrated_Location').item[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
```

If you would like to use `XPath` instead, you can use this function from [Select Single IXMLNode / TXmlNode Using XPath In Delphi's XmlDom](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphi-tips-2011/qt/select-single-node-ixmlnode-txmlnode-xpath-delphi-xmldom.htm) article:

```
class function TXMLNodeHelper.SelectNode(xnRoot: IXmlNode; const nodePath: WideString): IXmlNode;
var
  intfSelect : IDomNodeSelect;
  dnResult : IDomNode;
  intfDocAccess : IXmlDocumentAccess;
  doc: TXmlDocument;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if not Assigned(xnRoot)
    or not Supports(xnRoot.DOMNode, IDomNodeSelect, intfSelect) then
    Exit;

  dnResult := intfSelect.selectNode(nodePath);
  if Assigned(dnResult) then
  begin
    if Supports(xnRoot.OwnerDocument, IXmlDocumentAccess, intfDocAccess) then
      doc := intfDocAccess.DocumentObject
    else
      doc := nil;
    Result := TXmlNode.Create(dnResult, nil, doc);
  end;
end;
```

This way:

```
lx1.Items.Add(TXMLNodeHelper.SelectNode(XMLDocument1.DocumentElement, '//Location').NodeValue);
```

Comment: Works like I charm, I am using SelectNode with XPath because location could appear in other nodes so this seems to be the most reliable way.